# Connect to Azure Redis Cache as Service using Jedis

Tags: java, azure, caching, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to connect to the Azure Redis Cache Service, from outside the Azure using the sample code given on their site

```
            boolean useSsl = false;
            /* In this line, replace <name> with your cache name: */
            JedisShardInfo shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo("HOST_NAME", 6379, useSsl);
            shardInfo.setPassword(ACCESS_KEY); /* Use your access key. */
            shardInfo.setConnectionTimeout(999999);
            shardInfo.setSoTimeout(999999);
            Jedis jedis = new Jedis(shardInfo);
            jedis.set("foo", "bar");
            String value = jedis.get("foo");
```

I am getting the below exception while executing the program from outside of Azure

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
       at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)
       at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:239)
       at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:96)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:126)
       at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.set(BinaryClient.java:110)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Client.set(Client.java:47)
       at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.set(Jedis.java:120)
       at com.oriental.redis.cache.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:65)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
       at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:196)
       ... 11 more
```

The error suggests that the Azure Redis server never acknowledged the connection.
I am using basic Azure Subscription so did not create any premium instance, The documentation says that the Firewall / IP Access filters are applicable only with the Premium version of Azure Redis Cache.

This is confusing me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to port 6379 (the non-ssl port), you have to explicitly turn on that port.  By default, Azure Redis requires an encrypted connection (via port 6380).  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-configure#access-ports for more details.

Comment: Thanks @JonCole, I have already turned on the 6379 but the issue was that the network firewall was blocking the connection to outside azure cloud. It started working fine once the outgoing connection for the port was unblocked.